# Pass attributes to class in new Tkinter frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to pass the variable id in the function read_card(), which have been read by MFRC522, to the class MenuPage. MenuPage is a new Tkinter frame which I want to open. Somehow, it doesn't work. I receive an argument error. It's expecting 3 arguments, but I only give 2. Can you help me?

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

import tkMessageBox

def on_closing():
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Beenden", "Wollen Sie Pi Banking beenden?"):
        app.destroy()

def read_card():
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()

    try:
        id, text = reader.read_no_block()

        if id != None:
            menuPage = MenuPage(id)
            app.switch_frame(menuPage)
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Fehler", "Die Karte konnte nicht gelesen werden. Bitte halten Sie Ihre Karte zum NFC-Kontaktpunkt und versuchen Sie es erneut.")    
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title("Pi Banking")
        master.attributes('-zoomed', True)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Pi Banking", font=("Helvetica", 48, 'bold'))
        label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Raspi.png"))
        panel = tk.Label(self, image = self.logo)
        panel.pack()

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Bitte halten Sie Ihre Karte zum NFC-Kontaktpunkt und klicken Sie auf \"Karte lesen\"!", font=("Helvetica", 16))
        label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Karte lesen", font=("Helvetica", 16), command=read_card)
        button.pack()

class MenuPage(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master, card_id):
        self.card_id = card_id
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title("Pi Banking - Menu")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    app.mainloop()
```

The error I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "bankomat.py", line 20, in read_card
    menuPage = MenuPage(id)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* error traceback.

Comment: You passed an instance of `MenuPage` to `app.switch_frame()` which expects a class reference.

Comment: @acw1668 I changed to MenuPage(id) but I still get the same error

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. You are only passing `id` to `MenuPage`, but it requires an id and a master window.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have passed an instance of `MenuPage` to `app.switch_frame()` which expects a class reference.

You can change `switch_frame()` function as below:

```
def switch_frame(self, frame_class, *args, **kwargs):
    new_frame = frame_class(self, *args, **kwargs)
    if self._frame is not None:
        self._frame.destroy()
    self._frame = new_frame
    self._frame.pack()
```

Then call `app.switch_frame()` in `read_card()` as below:

```
if id is not None:
    app.switch_frame(MenuPage, id)
else:
    tkMessageBox.showerror(...)
```

Comment: This isn't the cause of the error in the question. This is another problem, but not the one being asked about.

Comment: It is the answer to OP original question which use `MenuPage(app, id)` instead of `MenuPage(id)`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification.